# Work(ing) atmosphere vs. work environment

Tags: word-usage

I was wondering which form is correct and how the words are usually used. I am asking, because I couldn't find a definite answer online.

1. question: which form is correct? Work atmosphere or working atmosphere?
2. question: are atmosphere and environment synonyms in this context?

   1. Google ngrams shows me that two forms, work atmosphere and working atmosphere, exist and that "working atmosphere" is slighly more common (which surprised me). However, compared to "work environment", both forms are rarely used. 
      I know that I am a bit biased as a German native speaker since "work atmosphere" is a direct translation, so it might simply be a germanism?
   2. So do the words atmosphere and environment actually mean the same in this context? To me, it feels like environment is more physical, while atmosphere rather relates to the mindset of people.

I am asking, because I wanted to write something like: 
'His energetic, “can-do” attitude contributes to a positive work atmosphere within the team.'

What is the best version of this phrase in your oppinion?

Thanks for your feedback & all the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in feeling that "atmosphere" relates more to interpersonal relationships within the workspace than "environment".

So, you saying

> His energetic, “can-do” attitude contributes to a positive work atmosphere within the team.

Makes perfect sense to me as a native English speaker.

"Working environment" relates to the larger picture in terms of the physical workspace and the people within it.  Usage can be ambiguous, but should be clear from context.

> *A "toxic working environment"*

usually is a personal thing - bullying boss, gossiping, arguments, etc.

> *A "harsh working environment"*

can infer heat, noise, discomfort - working in an iron foundry or factory for example

> *A "pleasant working environment"*

can be both - pleasant people, and a comfortable/peaceful workspace.

But yes, "atmosphere" in this case is interpersonal rather than environmental in nature.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and very helpful reply. 
That's a great explaination.
And I just found out that both forms, work and work*ing* environment/atmosphere are correct.